# Woocommerce: Add new VAT lines to an order programmatically

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

For a specific variable product category, I check which attributes are in the selected variation. Then I must update the order meta with these 2 different VAT and the total.

Instead of displaying the default woocommerce VAT detail line, I need to display these 2 lines with the total.

I don't display VAT in woocommerce so maybe it could be displayed as fee line, the important is that it is displayed on the invoice.

I started with the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'get_cart_info_woo');
function get_cart_info_woo() {
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
      
      $terms = get_the_terms( $product['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
      $inscription = $terms[0]->term_id;
      if ( $inscription == 19 )
      { /// if registering product
      $accomodation = $product['variation']['attribute_pa_hebergement'];
      $price  = $product['variation']['attribute_pa_tarif'];
    }
    }
 
// get the integers in the strings
     $accomodation_price = (int) filter_var($accomodation, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
     $price = (int) filter_var($price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// vat calculations     
     $accomodation_vat = $accomodation_price / 1.055 ;// VAT (5.5%)
     $price_vat = $_price / 1.2 ;// VAT (20%)

//here update order VAT meta with  $accomodation_vat and $price_vat as 2 different vat lines 
}
```

But I don't know if it is the good way.

Comment: **The variable `$matches` is not defined in your code**, so it can't work. This doesn't seems the right way to do it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ok updated.

Comment: The the final goal is to update order VAT meta with  $accomodation_vat and $price_vat as 2 different vat lines, right?… Where? On admin order items? On customer order items?  … Please try to clarify your question giving some more context on what you are trying to do and why… Without a clear question, you will not get anything useful.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks i did, i hope it is more clear now. Yes the value to use are  $accomodation_vat and $price_vat

Comment: In WooCommerce, Vat is calculated by item which has only ONE available tax rate by item… Everything is linked and related in WooCommerce. So this will not work in this simple way that you are trying. Only booking plugins can allows that in a complex way that is a real development.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Actually i need to display this data only in my invoice (https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/) Maybe possible to hook with it ?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec maybe a solution here : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hook-vat/#post-14185755

Comment: @LoicTheAztec As i don't use VAT in WC, maybe i could simply add a fee line and call it VAT ? woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees